# Mysql 5.7 Slave replication is Slow

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, aws, master-slave-replication

We are trying to debug a slave lag issue - it is currently lagging behind the master by 24 hours.

- Deployed on a AWS EC2 machine
- Database size is around 600 GB
- Grows at roughly 500 MB to 1 GB per day

In order to debug this problem , we bumped the instance type from "c5a.xlarge" with baseline IOPS of 1600 and peak 13000 IOPS for 30 minutes. We changed the EBS volume from gp2 to io2 also.

- EC2 current configuration is  "r6a.4xlarge" which is 16 CPU and 128 GB
- EC2 baseline is set to 16000 IOPS
- EBS volume choosen is io2 @ 32000 IOPS

**The lag issue has not significantly improved.**

With such a large EC2 instance and high performance EBS volume, it boils down to whether MySQL configuration is optimal or not.

What MySQL slave settings which should be looked at that can reduce the lag, considering it has high CPU, RAM, and disk capacity.

**Currently I see around 2GB of binary files in Slave** i.e. about one day's worth of binary logs.

Comment: Are you doing multi-row `UPDATEs` or `DELETEs`?  Is the slowlog turned on with `long_query_time no higher than `1`?

Comment: You may find this query assists with identifying troubled tables.

# if this helps you, please email SHAREABLE comments to info@mysqlservertuning.com
# 20210621 09:14 adapted from 
# https://www.percona.com/blog/2014/05/02/how-to-identify-and-cure-mysql-replication-slave-lag/
SELECT t.table_schema,t.table_name,engine,table_rows 
FROM information_schema.tables t INNER JOIN information_schema .columns c 
on t.table_schema=c.table_schema and t.table_name=c.table_name 
GROUP BY t.table_schema,t.table_name 
HAVING sum(if(column_key in ('PRI','UNI'), 1,0)) =0 
;

Comment: Did the above query find any schema,table names that had NO Primary or Unique indexes?  How many?  Absence of Primary and Unique indexes makes Replication LAG.

Comment: Additional DB information request, please.  TWO SETS, one from Primary and one set from REPLICA.
OS, Version? 
Instance type on each server, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

One reason the replica may be falling behind is the difference between the multiple concurrent writes on the primary server and the single (by default) write thread on the replica. The setting of `replica_parallel_workers` should not be much lower than the number of concurrent active connections on the primary, for the replica to be able to keep up. Also make sure you have "group commit" occurring -- check [this article](https://www.percona.com/blog/a-dive-into-mysql-multi-threaded-replication/) for a good discussion.

Comment: will try this out -